# Java, combining classes

Tags: java, class, printing

i'm running into a problem, recently picked up Java and now i'm doing some assignment but can't seem to figure out the solution, the output i get is below, i can't figure out how to instead of that random menu@somenumber, it would for example first one be Lunch, and yes i know i still need actual menu items printing

Restaurant 'Awsome'

- Menu:Menu@2389b9bd
- Menu:Menu@27013985

Restaurant 'Okay'

- Menu:Menu@41675ec4
- Menu:Menu@697eb767

Restaurant 'Lame'

- Menu:Menu@7e3b014c
- Menu:Menu@53d26552

Code:

```
class RestaurantTest {

   public static Restaurant[] init()
   {
      MenuItem[] AwsomeLunch = { new MenuItem ("Chicken", 5.2 ), new MenuItem ("Sarma", 3.1) };
      MenuItem[] AwsomeDinner = { new MenuItem ("Steak", 10.2 ), new MenuItem ("Squid", 8.2) };   
      MenuItem[] OkayLunch = { new MenuItem ("Kebab", 6.1 ), new MenuItem ("Ćevapi", 3.7) };  
      MenuItem[] OkayDinner = { new MenuItem ("Sharksteak", 11.4 ), new MenuItem ("Pizza", 6.2) };
      MenuItem[] LameLunch = { new MenuItem ("Burek", 2.5 ), new MenuItem ("Wiener Schiniztel", 4.3) };
      MenuItem[] LameDinner = { new MenuItem ("Octopus", 11.4 ), new MenuItem ("Kalja", 0.1) };


      Menu[] MenuAwsome = { new Menu ("Lunch", AwsomeLunch), new Menu("Dinner", AwsomeDinner) };
      Menu[] MenuOkay = { new Menu ("Lunch", OkayLunch), new Menu("Dinner", OkayDinner) };
      Menu[] MenuLame = { new Menu ("Lunch", LameLunch), new Menu("Dinner", LameDinner) };

      Restaurant[] listOfRestaurants = { new Restaurant ("Awsome", "Vukovarska 111", MenuAwsome), new Restaurant ("Okay", "Stradun 222", MenuOkay), new Restaurant ("Lame", "Ilica 333", MenuLame)};
      return listOfRestaurants;

   }  
   public static void main (String[] arguments){

      Restaurant[] listOfRestaurants = init();

      Restaurant awsome = listOfRestaurants[0];
      Restaurant okay = listOfRestaurants[1];
      Restaurant lame = listOfRestaurants[2];

      System.out.println(awsome.getName());



      System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Running 'Restaurant Menu Search':");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

      for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
          System.out.println("Restaurant '" + listOfRestaurants[i].getName() + "'"); 

          for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
            System.out.println("- Menu:" +  (listOfRestaurants[i].getMenu())[j]);
         }






      }





   } 
}
```

Comment: Do you override `toString()` in your classes?

Comment: Override `toString()` method ot `Restaurant` and `MenuItem`

Comment: What are the method in Menu class ?

Comment: I still didn't get to the part where I'm printing out actual meals and their prices, that's in MenuItem

Comment: @user2627736 You should print it inside the second loop, look the example [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24107148/573032).

Answer (score 0):

Basically your problem is in this line:

```
System.out.println("- Menu:" +  (listOfRestaurants[i].getMenu())[j]);
```

The random number you are getting is the reference address of the object of type menu. This number means that you are printing the toString() of the object Menu which, if not overwirten, prints the reference of the object. So to fix this, you either call getName() for the menu (if defined), so you statement will something like this:

```
System.out.println("- Menu:" +  (listOfRestaurants[i].getMenu())[j].getName());
```

Or define a toString() that will print the name of the menu like this:

```
Stirng toString(){
    return this.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should print some properties from `Menu` class instead of object reference like `Menu:Menu@7e3b014c`. For example

```
Menu m = listOfRestaurants[i].getMenu()[j];
System.out.println("Menu "+m.getName());
MenuItem[] launch = m.getLaunch();
for (MenuItem mi: launch)
  System.out.println("MenuItem "+mi.getName()+",  price "+mi.getPrice());
```